# What is the true meaning of common era?

Tags: meaning

As AD = Anno Domini/year of our lord
and BC = Before Christ,
BCE = Before Common Era,
CE = Common Era. 
What does common era mean?

Comment: "BCE and CE are alternatives to the Dionysian BC and AD system respectively" ~ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Era

Comment: OED: "Common|"  = 4. Of general application, general.

Comment: The reason is a matter of history.  There are many dating systems.  Writers of Athens and Rome dated by the year of annually elected officials (in Rome, consulships).  Roman historians moved to dating from the (mythical) foundation of Rome (BC753).  With the adoption of the Christian religion by the Roman emperor, Constantine, dating in the Christian world came to start from the birth of Christ.  The Arab and Hebrew worlds had different start dates.  The military and  cultural dominance of Europe made BC/AD dominant.  Now that dominance of 1 religion is objectionable and CE is preferred.